# onClick error javascript

Tags: javascript, nodejs, onclick

Que tal tengo el siguiente problema, estoy haciendo una lista de usuarios registrados en una bd, los listo con **innerHTML**. Hasta ahí todo bien, pero cuando quiero resaltar el nombre del usuario seleccionado con el evento **onClick** me sale el siguiente error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Alexeni is not defined
>       at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (asistencia.php:1)

Aquí el código para listar los usuarios.

```
usuarios.innerHTML += `

        <li class="active grey lighten-3 p-2" style="border: 1px solid red; margin-bottom:5px;">
            <a onclick="usuarioSeleccionado(${datos.name});" class="d-flex justify-content-around align-items-center">
                <img src="${datos.img}" alt="avatar" class="rounded-circle mr-2"
                    style="width:70px; height:70px;">
                <div class="text-small">
                    <strong>${datos.name}</strong>
                    <!--<p class="last-message text-muted">Hola</p>-->
                </div>
                <div class="chat-footer">
                    <p class="text-smaller text-muted mb-0"></p>
                    <span class="badge badge-danger float-right"></span>
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>

`;
```

Comment: Prueba pasando la variable `${datos.name}` entre comillas, para que lo vea como un `string` y no como una variable con el nombre del valor que contenga `name`.

Comment: ¿has probado a modificar tu onclick a esto? `onclick="usuarioSeleccionado('${datos.name}');"`

Comment: Gracias, era eso.